# Designing a Diode Clamp Current Source with calculations

Tags: analog

I have an assignment for our analog electronics module for the university to design a polygraph circuit using a Transimpeadance circuit, coupled with a Diode voltage-clamp current source to give the constant required reference voltage. I'm not going to lie this year I have not been productive being that covid has made work very busy and being a part-time student is very hard, and with the uni's  VLE (their online databases storing all the required course notes and videos) being hacked over the Xmas holidays most of the class is dangerously behind. If anyone can take their time and explain how to do this problem you will have saved the course for not only me but for all the other students. I have attached the section I am having problems with here, the whole circuit has to be simulated in LT spice as well
[image]

Comment: If you don't already know what they are, then you need to start by looking up the terms in the task.  Draw what you think the task is asking for as a circuit sketch and add it to the question.  Attempt to solve the problem and simulate the circuit.

Comment: You are right to suggest that approach to me for this task. Dude I am a part time student current working as a engineering tech for a big engineering company. What I usually do is I would revise through the whole module through the Xmas break with the slideshows and lecture vids. But this year the university website was hacked and we were not able to get the revision in. And i can't make up for the lost time being that january is a busy time for us at work. So some guidance, just a screen shot on how the circuit would look would be a big help